# grunt qunit in conjunction with grunt server

Tags: phantomjs, gruntjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

While running `grunt server` for developing, How can I separately use the `grunt qunit` task to run the tests.
While trying to pass `["test/**/*.html"]`  to the `all` property, but that fails to run and returns (`Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (0ms) Use`)

It looks like, it doesn't fire off a phantomjs instance and doesn't find these pates. 
So I tried the following

```
    grunt.initConfig({
     ....  

        qunit: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/test/tests/foo.html']
                }
            }
        }
    ....

});
```

It only works if when manually include all test html pages (like in the example).
The problem is
My Question is, can grunt qUnit work properly even while using grunt server.
And how can i have `["test/**/*.html"]` syntax work correctly. I am sure there must be a better way this should work! 
Also, how can use grunt.file.expand be utilized to programmatically add matching files to run in the grunt qunit task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  'qunit': {
        'files': ['test/**/*.html']
  }
  ...
});
...
// Wrap the qunit task
grunt.renameTask('qunit', 'contrib-qunit');
grunt.registerTask('qunit', function(host, protocol) {
    host = host || 'localhost';
    protocol = protocol || 'http';
    // Turn qunit.files into urls for conrib-qunit
    var urls = grunt.util._.map(grunt.file.expand(grunt.config.get('qunit.files')), function(file) {
        return protocol + '://' + host + '/' + file;
    });
    var config = { 'options': { 'urls' : urls } };
    grunt.config.set('contrib-qunit.all', config);
    grunt.task.run('contrib-qunit');
});
```